# Can I vent my portable air conditioner into my garage?

Tags: venting

I have casement windows and venting through the window is funky at best.  This portable AC is a single room unit, and I am considering a direct vent into the garage.  The garage is large (3+) with a large window.  During hot weather at least 1 garage door plus the window are open.

Comment: They do make air conditioners specifically for casement windows. Google it.

Comment: You will also need to find a way to drain the condensate.

Answer (score 2):

I did this and had no issues at all, I just open the garage window to let the heat out, also my bud who owns a heat and air company said he has done it many times on jobs. One being a fire station where they put 5 units that vent into engine bays..with no problems or issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could but generally, you shouldn't because what will happen is, the garage will get hot which will make it more difficult for the AC to release heat; the AC will be fighting to push hot air into a hot room. Plus, walls are not perfect insulators. Having a hot room against the house certainly isn't helpful. Also, there are probably some chemicals stored in the garage (paint, gasoline, etc.,) which should be stored at cool temps.

Now, not all garages are built the same. If it is well ventilated it might not be a huge issue. It's possible that's exactly what you have, but I'd guess it's probably a borderline situation, because you asked. Also, you have to think, what if you forget to open the door one day? Does the gasoline evaporate? Pop goes the house?